# Form Values are not displaying in same view

Tags: android, android-activity

I have developed a simple form within an activity.
My requirement is that when I click a send button, the form data is displayed in same the form layout

But this program is not displaying any field data.
No error is thrown.

**Main_Activity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
   // private static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.";
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void sendMessage(View view){
        EditText editText1 =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        String message1 =editText1.getText().toString();
        Log.v("ThisApp", message1);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message1);
   }
}
```

**activity_main.xml:-**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip">
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:background="#f3f3f3"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:hint="Name"/>
<Button
        android:id="@+id/sendButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: display form values in same view,but nothing will be displayed when i am click send button.

Comment: you are creating and filling a textview, but you are not doing anything with it

Answer (score 0):

Put `TextView` in same layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:background="#f3f3f3"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:hint="Name"/>
<Button
        android:id="@+id/sendButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/showText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="..."
        android:background="#f3f3f3"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:hint="..."/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then reference it from `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
   // private static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.";
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button myButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
        EditText editText1 =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showText);           


        myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
        String message1 =editText1.getText().toString();
         textView.setText(message1);

        } 
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: It is `TextView`, that will show what you have entered in `EditText`. Dont you want to display text you entered in same screen?

Comment: @user change your MainActivity now and run